# How can I run an Android service continuously

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

How can I run an Android service continuously even after clearing the running apps(RAM)...please provide me the code of service instead of reffering me the Android developers
my code is given below:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent1, int flags, int startId) {
    // do your jobs here
    return super.onStartCommand(intent1, flags, startId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return either [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) or [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) from onStartCommand depending on your needs.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
            return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent1, int flags, int startId) {
            // do your jobs here
            return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

As stated in developer site, if you don't intend to pass any intent to start the service then simply return START_STICKY flag. This will recreate the service with a blank intent object.

Answer (score 0):

you have return the service as sticky , like this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```